# ActionResult to do nothing or render a PartialView given a certain condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code:

```
public ActionResult SampleResult()
{
    Model model = new Survey();;

    .
    . Do something with model here
    .

    if (model.Id == 0)
    {
        //return EmptyResult();
        return DoNothing(); //How?
    }
    return PartialView("MyView", model);
}
```

I want to do nothing when model.Id==0
else render partialview.

Comment: return null ???

Comment: Btw the partial view will get rendered in a modal.  I tried returning null but i still triggers the show modal and my screen is greyed out.

Comment: ah - but that "the modal still shows" part is something you should mention in your original question. It's a rather important part of the solution.

Comment: where is your modal javascript code?

Comment: Do an undefined check in your js. if(result){ //show modal}

Comment: I have managed to solve the issue.  Since the partial view is being called by ajax, all I have to do is to check the data returned in the success callback. If data is empty dont do anything if it contains the partial view show modal.

Comment: `throw new HttpException(404, "Survey not Found");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just return same view as like below

```
public ActionResult SampleResult(Survey surveyModel)
{
Model model = new Survey();;

.
. Do something with model here
.

if (model.Id != 0)
{

     return PartialView("MyView", model);
}
  return View(surveyModel);  
}
```